# Access serial port via php

Tags: php, serial-port

I tried playing around with accessing a serial port with PHP, but haven't had much luck.

I've tried using `fsockopen`, `fopen`, `proc_open`, etc. I can't read or write to the socket.

Example:

```
$fp = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB0", "w+");
fwrite("enable");
echo fread($fp, 1024);
```

Comment: Does the user executing the script have write perms on that device?  `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: If you install a UUCP package, does `cu /dev/ttyUSB0` or `tip /dev/ttyUSB0` work as expected? (`screen` can also do serial things, if you don't have easy access to UUCP...)

Comment: I nevered accesssed a serial port in php, but shouldn't you be setting your baud, parity, stopbits, etc.. somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this many times in the past. Once was creating a management interface for a Cisco 2811. This may work for yours, although I am not sure of your IOS version (assuming Cisco because of your `fwrite();` through console).

See if your user has access to the device first. Easily, this can be done with `screen /dev/ttyUSB0`. Run your commands, to detach, press `ctrl+a` then `d`.

I most commonly use the [`stream_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.stream.php) family for something like this.

Here is an example:

```
$stream = stream_socket_client("udg:///dev/ttyUSB0", $errno, $errstr, 30);
fwrite($stream, "enable");

while(true){
    $line = stream_get_contents( $stream );
    if($line == 'exit'){
        break;
    }
}
```

By default, `stream_socket_client` starts in blocking mode, so you do not need to manually toggle it.

Another thing you can do if you dont mind installing an extension is the [`DirectIO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dio.php) extension. It possesses functions to allow you to set baud rate and all the goodies, [example here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dio-tcsetattr.php).

You can even take a look at this project: http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/source/browse/trunk/

Comment: DirectIO is the route i am going to take. Thank you!